# Open application several times in OS X

Tags: macos, applications

I am developing OS X version of multi-platform application. In Windows I can start several instances of application by just opening exe file several times.

I noticed that in OS X when I open my app it appears on panel, and when I start it for the second time - nothing happens.

Can I configure my app (edit .app folder) so it can start several instances of same app? I mean without reconfiguring my Mac, so I can deliver configured app to users. Is it possible?

Comment: The quick answer is no - however what sort of app is this, why do you want multiple instances?

Comment: @Mark GUI app with one window. Can I somehow catch some system call when user opens app second time to do some action like draw another window?

Comment: That is known as opening a new window - look at NSDocument and apps based on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may open a second instance of an application by entering in Terminal.app:

```
open -n /Path/To/Application.app
```

Some apps (e.g. iTunes.app) don't open an additional instance.